# How to know the upload/download progress with box.net API?

Tags: box-api

I would like to know if there is a way with the API to get the upload or download progress while sending or receiving files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We currently don't return in-progress upload/download status via the API, only status upon success/failure. This does seem like a good idea, for larger files in particular, and we'll consider this as we'll build out the API.

Comment: Curious if this ever happened, I haven't found anything in the content API documentation. Like you said, this would be very useful for large content uploads. Thanks!